# how to call a function in a exe and pass parameter in java

Tags: java, c#

I have created a exe from this c# class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using SharedClientAPI;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Reflection;
namespace JavaExeCallTest
{
    public class JavaExe
    {

        public JavaExe()
        {

        }

      public String testFromC(String str)
      {
      return "Hellow From C#:"+str;

      }
      }
    }
```

I have created the JavaEXeCallTest.exe. I need to call the testFromC(String str) function from java and print the message. How can do this in java

Comment: I think [jni4net](http://jni4net.com/) can do this.

Comment: @lllidans4 I want to use processbuilder in java

Comment: Can't you just make some event loop that dispatches the input to the functions depending on some starting input e.g. `while(true) if (args[0] == "testFromC") { testFromC(args[1]); }}` and pass function and arguments from the standard input

Comment: @Royal Bg Please provide me with a full code on how to do this am stack